# Prevent UISearchDisplayController from hiding under the navigation bar on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, uisearchbar, uisearchbardisplaycontrol

I have a tableview with view with search bar on top of the screen below navigation bar. There is also tab bar on this screen. When search controller is activated first, time search bar hides under navigation bar (Translucent set to NO).

In `viewDidLoad`, `searchDisplayControllerDidEndSearch` and `searchDisplayControllerWillBeginSearch` I am setting the search bar frame:

```
self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, width, 44);
```

I am not using AutoLayout